# How to handle echo json_encode() from PHP in C#?

Tags: c#, php

Hi everyone I'm working with C# and PHP, I'm sending data from C# to PHP file and this is working properly the issue I have is when I use echo `json_encode()` to send data back to C# but I don't know how to do this, only works if I just use a simple `echo "sometext"`

This my method from C#

```
private async void CheckLicense()
{
    string usuario = "USERX";
    string licencia = "E023-ED1F-3CAE-D492-1A3F";

    string url = "http://localhost/convertidorxml/php/verificarLicencia.php?usuario=" + usuario + "&licencia=" + licencia;

    HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    myRequest.Method = "GET";
    WebResponse myResponse = myRequest.GetResponse();
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(myResponse.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8);
    
    string result = sr.ReadToEnd();
    result.Replace('\n', ' ');

    sr.Close();
    myResponse.Close();
}
```

And this is the code from my PHP file

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: application/json');

require 'conexion.php';

//=============================================

if (isset($_GET['usuario']) && isset($_GET['licencia'])) {

    $usuario = trim($_GET['usuario']);
    $licencia = trim($_GET['licencia']);

    $existe = $conexion->query("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = '$usuario' AND licencia = '$licencia'");

    if ($existe->num_rows) {

        $actualizar = $conexion->query("UPDATE usuarios SET status = 1 WHERE usuario = '$usuario'");

        if ($actualizar) {

            echo json_encode(array('error' => false));
        }
    
    } else {

        echo json_encode(array('error' => true));
    }

} else {

    echo json_encode(array('error' => true));
}
```

What do I need to do to handle it as if I wanted to do in C# something like `if (error == false)` I hope I explained it good, hope you can help me please.

I want to handle the json data response in C#

Comment: Have you tried JSON.NET for C#?

Comment: Please don't do this: `$existe = $conexion->query("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario = '$usuario' AND licencia = '$licencia'");` parameterize your queries, or at the very least, make sure they are properly encoded.

Comment: @odan No, no idea about it, there is a way to solve it that way I have in my code?

Comment: @RobertMcKee yes i know but I'm just trying to make my code work, some tip or advice?

Comment: Is your PHP doing everything that you want it to be doing, and you are only concerned with the C#? Is that what I'm reading?

Comment: @ChrisHaas yes, that is correct, PHP is fine, is returning {"error": false} but I don't know how to handle it in my method of C# when is an object

Comment: Well, I'd ask what version of C# you are using.  Is it .NET Core 5? Then you'd use System.Text.Json.  If it's .NET Framework, or .NET Core 3.1 or lower, then you'd likely want to use NewtonSoft.  This might help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to?pivots=dotnet-5-0

Comment: @ProfessorZoom, the reason that I asked is that you can completely remove PHP from the question now, including the tags, and just say that you have `{"error": false}` that you want to parse as JSON in C#. There's a chance that the double-tags and extra unnecessary block of code is deterring people from helping further.